# Arrange date columns based on unique id column using R

Tags: r

I got large dataset like this

```
  structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), admi_number = c(1, 
    2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4), admission = c("2014-04-16", "2014-05-22", 
    "2014-12-20", "2014-12-18", "2014-01-01", "2014-06-01", "2016-01-01", 
    "2015-01-01"), discharge = c("2014-06-27", "2014-04-16", "2014-12-21", 
    "2014-12-23", "2014-01-06", "2014-06-10", "2015-01-10", "2016-02-01"
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

I would like to arrange the admission and discharge columns which are dates in ascending order based on the id column, so for each patient I have admission and discharged columns sorted like this

```
    structure(list(id2 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), admi_number2 = c(1, 
2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4), admission2 = c("2014-04-16", "2014-05-22", 
"2014-12-18", "2014-12-20", "2014-01-01", "2014-06-01", "2015-01-01", 
"2016-01-01"), discharge2 = c("2014-04-16", "2014-06-27", "2014-12-21", 
"2014-12-23", "2014-01-06", "2014-06-10", "2015-01-10", "2016-02-01"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, you can do this with `dplyr` (which can also be installed/loaded alongside some other useful packages as `tidyverse`)

```
a <- structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), admi_number = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4), admission = c("2014-04-16", "2014-05-22", "2014-12-20", "2014-12-18", "2014-01-01", "2014-06-01", "2016-01-01", "2015-01-01"), discharge = c("2014-06-27", "2014-04-16", "2014-12-21", "2014-12-23", "2014-01-06", "2014-06-10", "2015-01-10", "2016-02-01" )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))
b <- structure(list(id2 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), admi_number2 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4), admission2 = c("2014-04-16", "2014-05-22", "2014-12-18", "2014-12-20", "2014-01-01", "2014-06-01", "2015-01-01", "2016-01-01"), discharge2 = c("2014-04-16", "2014-06-27", "2014-12-21", "2014-12-23", "2014-01-06", "2014-06-10", "2015-01-10", "2016-02-01" )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

library(tidyverse)

a_new <- a %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(admission = sort(admission),
         discharge = sort(discharge))

all(a_new == b)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well here solution by using base R functions :

data<- structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2), admi_number = c(1,
2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4), admission = c("2014-04-16", "2014-05-22",
"2014-12-20", "2014-12-18", "2014-01-01", "2014-06-01", "2016-01-01",
"2015-01-01"), discharge = c("2014-06-27", "2014-04-16", "2014-12-21",
"2014-12-23", "2014-01-06", "2014-06-10", "2015-01-10", "2016-02-01"
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -8L))

str(data)

data$admission <- as.Date(data$admission,format = "%Y-%m-%d")

data$discharge <- as.Date(data$discharge,format = "%Y-%m-%d")

str(data)

A <- data[order(data[,"id"],data[,"admi_number"]), c("id","admi_number")]

B <- data[order(data[,"id"],data[,"admission"]),c("admission")]

C <- data[order(data[,"id"],data[,"discharge"]),c("discharge")]

AB <- cbind(A,B)

ABC <- cbind(AB,C)